# Powershell script (remote) to copy List items from MOSS 2007 to SharePoint Server 2010 

Tags: list, powershell, migration

Any one has any ideas if we can write PowerShell script from a server which does not have SharePoint installed to copy list items from a MOSS 2007 site (MOSS server) to SharePoint 2010 (SP2010 server)?

If no, does anyone know if we can run the PowerShell script from the SharePoint 2010 Server to copy list items from the remote MOSS 2010 server to SharePoint 2010?

Code samples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by calling the [Lists web service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.aspx) from System.Net.WebClient or otherwise from a server which does not have SharePoint installed, but the Object Model will not be available for full use.